# Uncaught exception 'com_exception' with message '<b> Source: </ b> Microsoft Word <b> Description: </ b> Command failed'

Tags: php, com, ms-word, office-interop

I had a problem on my script after I run the script had appeared **Uncaught
exception 'com_exception' with message ' Source: Microsoft Word Description: Command failed'**

and show alert :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYSwV.jpg

here is my code :

```
<?php
   $word = new COM("Word.Application") or die ("Could not initialise Object.");
   // set it to 1 to see the MS Word window (the actual opening of the document)
   $word->Visible = 0;
   // recommend to set to 0, disables alerts like "Do you want MS Word to be the default .. etc"
   $word->DisplayAlerts = 0;
   // open the word 2007-2013 document 
   $word->Documents->Open('C:\xampp\htdocs\Open_Office\test_4sk.docx');
   // save it as word 2003
   $word->ActiveDocument->SaveAs('C:\xampp\htdocs\Open_Office\newdocument.doc');
   // convert word 2007-2013 to PDF
   $word->ActiveDocument->ExportAsFixedFormat("C:\\xampp\htdocs\Open_Office\Main_PDF.pdf", 17, false, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, true, true, 2, true, true, false);
   // quit the Word process
   $word->Quit(false);
   // clean up
   unset($word);
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried surrouding your code with try..catch? put `try{` BEFORE everything and `}catch(Exception $e){ echo $e; }` AFTER everything.

Comment: This [comment](http://php.net/manual/en/class.com.php#90814) might be what you're looking for.

Comment: subhanallah thats the answer thanks @FirstOne

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to:

```
<?php
   try{
       $word = new COM("Word.Application") or die ("Could not initialise Object.");
       // set it to 1 to see the MS Word window (the actual opening of the document)
       $word->Visible = 0;
       // recommend to set to 0, disables alerts like "Do you want MS Word to be the default .. etc"
       $word->DisplayAlerts = 0;
       // open the word 2007-2013 document 
       $word->Documents->Open('C:\xampp\htdocs\Open_Office\test_4sk.docx');
       // save it as word 2003
       $word->ActiveDocument->SaveAs('C:\xampp\htdocs\Open_Office\newdocument.doc');
       // convert word 2007-2013 to PDF
       $word->ActiveDocument->ExportAsFixedFormat("C:\\xampp\htdocs\Open_Office\Main_PDF.pdf", 17, false, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, true, true, 2, true, true, false);
       // quit the Word process
       $word->Quit(false);
       // clean up
       unset($word);
   }catch(Exception $e){
       echo $e;
   }
?>
```

This way it won't stop the execution of your code AND you can see it in case it happens. Note that the ideal thing to do here is replace `echo $e;` with an actual error handling.

Comment: sorry @Firstone looks like I have to get 15 reputation score in advance to add your answer, if it can be I will give you score in your answer, cheers :)

Comment: Well you're almost there, if @FirstOne +1's your post and one of your comments, you'll make it past 15 rep points